# Drop Down is not working in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

here i am displaying 2 database tables i.e 1 is after entering user details user information is displaying another is displaying 10 chapter allocation to the entered user from chapter_subscription table.In chapter_subscription table there are

1. chapter number field
2. start date
3. end date

my aim is to create drop down option to end date so that user is allowed to choose it from the drop down.But my problem is i have used option tag ,when i run it is telling that unexpected for loop.Please can u help in resolving this error and make me to display drop down for each displayed  end date.As i am newbie to php .Thank you in advance.
insert_dummy.php

```
<?php

    include('db.php');




    $userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);



    $userEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']);
    $userPassword=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPassword']);
    $expiry_date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['expiry_date']);
    $expiry_date=date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime($expiry_date1));
    $end_date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
    $end_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end_date1));



     $regDate = date("Y-m-d");



    function generateCode($characters) 
    {
        $possible = '23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*';
        $code = '';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $characters) { 
            $code .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
            $i++;
        }
        return $code;
    }

    $registration_key=generateCode(10);



    $str="insert into coeds_user(userName,userEmail,userPassword,regDate,expiry_date,registration_key) values('$userName','$userEmail','$userPassword','$regDate','$expiry_date','$registration_key')";


    $query=mysql_query($str);
    $userid=mysql_insert_id();
    if($query)
    {
    $display="Success";
    }
    else
    {
    $display= "Failed";
    }
    $string="select * from coeds_user where userId=$userid";
    $query2=mysql_query($string);
    $display.="<table border='1' align='center'>";
    $display.="<tr><th>UserName</th><th>UserEmail</th><th>UserPassword</th><th>RegDate</th><th>ExpiryDate</th><th>RegistrationKey</th><th colspan='3'>Action</th></tr>";
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
    {
    $display.="<tr>";

    $display.="<td>".$result['userName']."</td>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['userEmail']."</td>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['userPassword']."</td>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['regDate']."</td>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['expiry_date']."</td>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['registration_key']."</td>";
    $display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' title='Edit' href='user_update.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']."'><img id='image' src='./images/small.gif'/></a></td>";
    $display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' href='user_delete.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']." '><img id='image' src='./images/trash.png'/></a></td>";



    $display.="</table>";
     $end_date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months"));
     $end_date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months"));
     $end_date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months"));
     $end_date4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 months"));
     $end_date5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+12 months"));
     $page="";


    $str="select chapter_no from chapter_details ";


    $query7=mysql_query($str);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($query7);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    $chap_lic=generateCode(50);
    $chapter_no=mysql_result($query7,$i,'chapter_no');
    $start_date=date('Y-m-d');
    $expiry_date=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
    $end_date=date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime("+3 months"));
    /*$end_date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
    $end_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($end_date1));*/
    $s="insert into chapter_subscriptions (userId,chapter_no,start_date,end_date) values($userid,$chapter_no,'$start_date','$end_date')";
    $end_date=date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime("+3 months"));

    $query8=mysql_query($s);
    }
    $strings="select * from chapter_subscriptions where userId=$userid";
    $query9=mysql_query($strings);
    $display.="<table border='1' align='center'>";
    $display.="<tr><th>ChapterNumber</th><th>StartDate</th><th>EndDate</th><th colspan='2'>Action</th></tr>";
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query9))
    {
    $display.="<tr>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['chapter_no']."</td>";
    $display.="<td>".$result['start_date']."</td>";


    $display.="<tr><select>".$result['end_date'].
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
    $display.="<td><option value=echo $end_date1;>echo $end_date1;</option></td>";
    $display.="<td><option value=echo $end_date2;>echo $end_date2;</option></td>";
    $display.="<td><option value=echo $end_date3;>echo $end_date3;</option></td>";
    $display.="<td><option value=echo $end_date4;>echo $end_date4;</option></td>";
    $display.="<td><option value=echo $end_date5;>echo $end_date5;</option></td>";

    }
    $display.="</select></tr>"
    $display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' title='Edit' href='chapter_subscription_update.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']."'><img id='image' src='./images/small.gif'/></a></td>";
    $display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' href='chapter_subscription_delete.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']." '><img id='image' src='./images/trash.png'/></a></td>";

    $display.="</tr>";
    }
    $display.="</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: check for Errors after executing SQL-statements

Comment: there is no error in sql query

Answer (score 0):

Learn how you can debug your code! Check [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) to learn how you can enable detailed errors. I'd also suggest you check [this handy guide](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/misc/php-errors-common-mistakes/) for common mistakes. And use an IDE that checks for common mistakes, or use an online [code validator](https://phpcodechecker.com). Stack Overflow is not a place to get debugging help, check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information on what you can ask here.

---

1) You have a line without a semi-colon (before the `for` loop that causes the error):

```
$display.="<tr><select>".$result['end_date'].
```

which should be like this:

```
$display.="<tr><select>".$result['end_date'];
```

2) You have a while loop that never closes (missing a `}` somewhere in your script):

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
```

3) and...

```
$display.="</select></tr>"
```

should be

```
$display.="</select></tr>";
```

Comment: I corrected but now it is telling that unexpected $display in line 227

Comment: $display.="<td><a id='colour' class='tooltip' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete' href='chapter_subscription_delete.php?user_Id=".$result['userId']." '><img id='image' src='./images/trash.png'/></a></td>";

Comment: @Vradhit Check edit, your forgot another semi-colon.